# How do I print without a newline after a time.sleep()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write Python code (in 3.x) that, for example, would `print` 'hello', wait half a second with `time.sleep` and then `print` 'world'. The code I have now is like this:

```
from time import sleep

print('hello', end = '')
sleep(0.5)
print(' world')
```

(the lack of a space in end = '' is there for a reason)

Output:

```
#waiting
>> hello world
```

Expected output:

```
>> hello /*waiting*/ world
```

please help.

Comment: Read [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) (which should have been the first thing to do).

Comment: @usr2564301 oh... might have been a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to print buffering (which is really handled by your operating system and not Python). This buffer is automatically flushed from time to time (usually pretty often), but you can request a flush at will. The `print()` function makes this easy:

```py
from time import sleep

print('hello', end='', flush=True)
sleep(0.5)
print(' world', flush=True)
```

Also, adding flushing to the last `print()` is probably not needed.